# Use Multiple Linq queries in each other

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Hi I use this code for deleting product object from DB

`_context.Products.Remove(_context.Products.Find(id));`

Is that true ? using Multiple Linq queries in each other ?

Comment: Your code is fine. Are you getting any error? In order to commit this deletion, you should call _context.SaveChanges() as well.

Comment: "Is that true?" Do you mean "is that OK?" If so, then sure, why not. Did you try it? Does it work? Do you get errors?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran it work well but I want to know it Ok to use or no. So that is ok ! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although what you are doing is fine. But it is not the preferred way of removing something from the database. I would suggest you to find the record first and then check if it is found or not. If record exist in the DB, then delete the record.

```
var result = _context.Products.Find(id);
if(result != null){
_context.Products.Remove(result);
_context.SaveChanges();
}
```